# Neural Network Memory

Tags: google-colaboratory

Using Google Colab, I made a neural network using tensorflow that generates text based on examples. I ran 60 epochs. How can I get my neural network to maintain what it has learned. Whenever I re-run it, it starts over.

Comment: Take a look here, it is about saving a model, not sure if it applies to your problem: https://medium.com/@ml_kid/how-to-save-our-model-to-google-drive-and-reuse-it-2c1028058cb2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try saving your model at the end of the training like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.keras.models.save_model(model, 'model/my_model')
```

Then you can load the model like this:

```
tf.keras.models.load_model('model/my_model')
```